# Получить все элементы, входящие в данный массив

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

**Задание:**  *Дано натуральное число N и одномерный массив A1, A2, ..., AN действительных чисел.
Получить все элементы, входящие в данный массив по одному разу.*
Задание нужно было выполнить используя указатели и динамический массив.Код работает не верно,думаю,что дело в неверно составленном цикле, помогите пожалуйста советом
Вот мой код:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int *ptr = NULL; //указатель на массив
int N, i;
printf ("Введите число N, которое так же будет размером массива: ");
scanf("%d", &N);
ptr = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

if (ptr == NULL) //проверка на выделение памяти
printf("\n Память не выделилась");
puts("Введите элементы массива.");

for (i = 0; i<N; i++) //ввод самих элементов
{ 
printf("Елемент[%d]=",i);
scanf("%d",ptr+i );
}

puts("Вывод всех ведденых элементов массива");
for (i = 0; i<N; i++){
printf("%d |", ptr[i]);
}

int *ptr_begin = ptr;
int *ptr_end = ptr + N - 1;
int *ptr_end2 = ptr_end;

for (ptr_begin = ptr; ptr_begin < ptr_end; ptr_begin++)
for (ptr_end2=ptr_end; ptr_end2!=ptr_begin; ptr_end2--)
if (*ptr_begin != *ptr_end2)
printf("\nЧисла которые не повторяются:%d", *ptr_begin);

free(ptr);
printf("\n--------------------------------------------------\n");
return main();
```

Вот,что в итоге получается, если например размер массива 3
[image: Вот,что в итоге получается, если например размер массива 3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что в условии - массив действительных чисел, а вы создаете и читаете массив `int`'ов...

Потом - что это??!! `return main();`?

Далее, цикл должен иметь вид (подумайте, что *на самом деле* делал ваш цикл - все ли числа проверял, когда именно выводил сообщение, сколько раз) -

```
for (ptr_begin = ptr; ptr_begin <= ptr_end; ptr_begin++)
{
    int is_the_same = 0;
    for (ptr_end2=ptr_end; ptr_end2!=ptr_begin; ptr_end2--)
        if (*ptr_begin == *ptr_end2)
        {
            is_the_same = 1;
            break;
        }
    if (is_the_same == 0) printf("\nЧисла которые не повторяются:%d", *ptr_begin);
}
```

Ну, и слово "Элемент" пишется через букву "Э".

**Update**

Да, действительно, у меня код не отрабатывал все повторы. Вот исправленный вариант:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int *ptr = NULL, *uniq; //указатель на массив
    int N, i,j;
    printf ("Введите число N, которое так же будет размером массива: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    ptr = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    uniq = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    if (ptr == NULL) //проверка на выделение памяти
        printf("\n Память не выделилась");
    puts("Введите элементы массива.");

    for (i = 0; i<N; i++) //ввод самих элементов
    {
        printf("Елемент[%d]=",i);
        scanf("%d",ptr+i );
        uniq[i] = 1;
    }

    puts("Вывод всех ведденых элементов массива");
    for (i = 0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d |", ptr[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(j = i+1; j < N; ++j)
        {
            if (ptr[i] == ptr[j]) uniq[i] = uniq[j] = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("\nЧисла которые не повторяются:");
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        if (uniq[i]) printf("  %d",ptr[i]);
    puts("");

    free(ptr);
    free(uniq);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!return main() использовала для зацикливания задания (

Comment: Единственное,что при условии что например все 3 элемента 111, то он выводит, что 1 не повторяется.Или же например, если 3 элемента, и это элементы (1,1,2),то он выводит 1 и 2.

Comment: Да, в самом деле. Исправился, см. ответ.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое,все работает теперь корректно!Я бы хотела очень понять, как этот код работает, не могли бы Вы по возможности и наличие свободного времени объяснить некоторые моменты которые мне не понятны.  1)  .Для чего вы прописали эту строчку, и что она делает,что означает - (int argc, const char * argv[])     2 )Для чего 2 указателя int *ptr = NULL, *uniq;     3)какую функцию выполняет эта строчка, в 1 цикле фор - uniq[i] = 1;   4) и по какому принципу здесь работает иф, -         
 for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        if (uniq[i]) printf("  %d",ptr[i]);

Comment: 1) Это у меня шаблон такой :) - это параметры, передаваемые через командную строку; для вас сейчас не играют роли. 2. Я держу еще один массив `uniq`, в котором отмечаю нулем найденные дубли. 3 - массив изначально инициализирую единицами (все уникальны), а уж потом убираем найденные дубли. 4 - просто иду по всем элементам и вывожу те, у которых флаг уникальности остался установленным.